# Sync iOS device from terminal

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, terminal

Since I work with Xcode and plug in and out iOS devices multiple times per day, I don't want iTunes to automatically backup them every time I plug them in. But at the same time I would like to have a daily backup of the devices.

So I was wondering - is there a way to trigger iOS sync with a terminal command, so then it can be scheduled to run every day?

Comment: Check [this very old article](https://www.engadget.com/2008/01/16/terminal-tip-syncing-your-iphone-or-ipod-touch-from-the-command/). I _think_ it should still work. The path changed to `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/reenumerate_ios_devices`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Find your device Product ID and Vendor ID from System Information.app in the Utilities folder.

   [image]
2. Run the following

   ```
   /System/L*/Priv*/MobileD*/V*/A/reenumerate_ios_devices vendorid productid
   ```

   Replace ‘vendorid’ with your Vendor ID and ‘productid’ with your Product ID.

Comment: Have the same IDs, so ran the command: "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/reenumerate_ios_devices 0x05ac 0x12a8" but nothing happens.

Comment: Anything new on this one?

Comment: This ist not available Bro. `ls -1 /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/`